# How to install dual monitors on Dell with Windows 10?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a new Dell Optiplex 760 desktop PC with Windows 10.

I would like to add a second flat screen monitor.  How do I determine what dual monitor card to install?

Are there program changes that must be made in Windows 10?

Any suggestions or information will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You (may) have a SFF (Small Form Factor) computer. It cannot hold full-height extension cards. That means you have to be very careful when selecting the graphics card. It *must* come with a low-profile bracket.

Due to design shortcomings, your system also does not support dual-slot cards.

This leaves you with a relatively small selection of cards that usually come with DVI and HDMI, like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102933). This specific model even allows you to place the VGA connector in a separate slot in the vicinity. Because you can also place it “behind” the card, it is fully compatible with your system.

However, I’m a little sceptical: You say you have a *new* Optiplex 760. However, this model is 8 years old.

Comment: Thank you Daniel,  You are correct in regard to the "NEW".  I have no knowledge of Dell models.  Dell was purchased as refurbished.  Looks new.  Has 1T HD with Windows 10  Case is full size with room for full size cards. Has three slots, 2 white 1 black.  I put in video card with 2 flat screens, but output on both is fuzzy, impossible to read.  I am now searching for screen adjustments but could find none.  Windows 10 is very user unfriendly.  I have XP on my "old" computer, with two other monitors and a different video card.  Any further comment would be greatly appreciated!   Eric

Comment: @I'mEricWhoRU could you perhaps provide both a photo and a screenshot? This issue might be better suited for a new question, seeing how the original goal was achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/how-connect-multiple-monitors) say more than 1000 answers!

Short discription:

Take any graphic card with multiple ports and build it in your pc. Make sure you have all drivers installed. Then follow just the instruction which I have linked!
[image]